# Get Large File Size in C

Tags: c, large-files, portability, filesize, ftell

Before anyone complains of "duplicate", I've been checking SO quite thoroughly, but there seem to be no clean answer yet, although the question looks quite simple.

I'm looking for a **portable C code**, which is able to provide the size of a file, even if such a file is bigger than 4GB.

The usual method (`fseek`, `ftell`) works fine, as long as the file remains < 2GB. It's fairly well supported everywhere, so I'm trying to find something equivalent.

Unfortunately, the updated methods (`fseeko`, `ftello`) are not supported by all compilers. For example, MinGW miss it (and obviously MSVC). Furthermore, some comments make me believe that the new return type (off_t) does not necessarily support size > 2GB, it may depend on some external parameters, to be checked.

The unambiguous methods (`fseeko64`, `ftello64`) are not supported by MSVC. MS provides their equivalent, `_fseeki64` & `_ftelli64`. This is already bad, but it becomes worse : some Linux configurations seem to badly support these functions during run time. For example, my Debian Squeeze on PowerPC, using GCC 4.4, will produce a "filesize" method using `fseeko64` which always return 0 (while it works fine for Ubuntu64). MinGW seems to answer some random garbage above 2GB.

Well, I'm a bit clueless as far as portability is concerned. And if I need to make a bunch of `#if #else`, then why not go straight to the OS & compilers specifics methods in the first place, such as `GetFileSize()` for MSVC for example.

Comment: Well, what is your definition of "portable"? There are many systems that can't even open files. Even more that cannot open files over 4 GB in size.

Answer (score 10):

You said it: there's no portable method; if I were you I'd just go with `GetFileSize` on Windows and `stat` on POSIX.

Comment: You could use `_stat64` on Windows to keep the code *sorta* the same.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: correct, although I don't know if every compiler on Windows implement it (while `GetFileSize` is part of the Windows API, so it should always be available).

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use [`stat64` on Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat64) and [`_stat64` on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff%28VS.80%29.aspx) to get file size information for files over 2 GBs, and both functions are very similar in usage. You can also use a couple of `#define`s to use `stat64` on Windows too:

```
#if __WIN32__
#define stat64 _stat64
#endif
```

However, although this should work, it should be noted that the `_stat` family of functions on Windows is really just a wrapper around other functions, and will add additonal resources and time overhead.

Answer (score 6):

```
int ch;
FILE *f = fopen("file_to_analyse", "rb");
/* error checking ommited for brevity */
unsigned long long filesize = 0; /* or unsigned long for C89 compatability*/
while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) filesize++;
fclose(f);
/* error checking ommited for brevity */
```

Comment: Ok, it's the only standard compliant way, but I hope you are being sarcastic: reading a whole file, possibly 2+ GB big, one character at time just to know its size (which on current filesystems is simply an attribute of the file) is plain stupid...

Comment: Oh, no, no, no... please tell me you're kidding. On the other hand, the question is about a portable way, not about an efficient one. This is a portable way indeed.

Comment: It's event-driven, which is the reason why it's so fast.

Comment: Why is this so bad? How else would you count all the bytes, you would have to iterate over them and actually count them to find out, right?

Comment: @Gerard Because the filesystem counts bytes *when they are written*, and then stores the value away. That's how it knows what EOF is. Reading massive files in their entirety to determine size is slow, reading a pre-calculated field stored in the filesystem is fast.

Comment: @Gerard Do you have to read every page of a book to find out how many pages it has? And if you did, would you ask why that's so bad?

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented and tested the following:

```
#if __WIN32__
#define stat64 _stat64
#endif
```

using MinGW64 gcc compiler 4.8.1 and Linux gcc 4.6.3
compiles and works.

On OSX, no redefinition of stat required.

for lstat and fstat functions I expect similar macro #defines to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include sys/stat.h

off_t fsize(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st; 

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `lseek()` (or `_lseek()`) with `SEEK_END`? It returns the offset sought to.

Under linux `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` needs to be defined to `64` for `lseek()` to return 64bit values (which should be the default anyhow).

Comment: I've not tried it yet. It seems lseek() might have the same sort of problem as fseeko() : the used type (off_t) may or may not support values above 2GB, depending on some external configuration.

Comment: @Attract: I tested this under 32/64bit linux using `gcc` and under 32bit win-vista using `VC10`.