# "fseeko64 was not declared in this scope" (mingw, windows)

Tags: c++, mingw

Just try to compile this c++ code with MINGW

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char file_name[100] = "test";
    pFile = fopen (file_name,"rb");
    fseeko64(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    long long file_dim = ftello64 (pFile);
    printf ("File:\n%s\ncontains %I64d bytes:\n", file_name, file_dim);
    return 0;
}
```

and always get

```
'fseeko64' was not declared in this scope
'ftello64' was not declared in this scope
```

Why? What's wrong??

**Upd:**

I've found reason: "-std=c++11" switch gives this! "-std=gnu++11" OK

Comment: I've never heard of `fseeko64` or `ftello64`. Are they standard functions? If not your compiler probably doesn't implement them, or implements them outside of `stdio.h`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Large File Size in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026896/get-large-file-size-in-c)

Comment: They are part of stdio.h, I can see them there. There are a lot of information about them in google.

Comment: If they are in the `stdio.h` that your compiler is picking, you wouldn't get those errors.  What does the preprocessor output look like?

Comment: I've found reason: "-std=c++11" switch!

"-std=gnu++11" OK