# Getting file size platform-independently (C)

Tags: c, file, cross-platform, standards, filesize

I am looking for some **platform-independent** C code to determine the size of a given file. First, I read the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/238607

The answer uses fseek with SEEK_END and ftell. Now, my problem is that I found the following C standard quotes.

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

and

> A binary stream need not meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.

So, it looks like I have a problem. Possibly, the following code, which counts the number of read bytes, is a workaround.

```
file = fopen(file_path, "rb");
/* ... */
while ( EOF != fgetc(file) ) {
  ret = size_t_inc(&file_size_); /* essentially, this does ++file_size_ */
  /* ... */
}
ret = feof(file);
/* ... */
if (!ret) {
  return 1; /* Error! */
}
```

(entire function here: https://github.com/630R6/bytelev/blob/8e3d0dd14042f16086f3ca4e9a33d49a0629630e/main.c#L138)

Still, I am looking for a better solution.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Using `stat` function?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026896/get-large-file-size-in-c/9026937

Comment: An answer from the question linked by *pmg*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9027012/694576

Comment: @EugeneSh. is it available on every platform?

Comment: On windows you need to use `_stat64()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) for file sizes larger then 32bit.

Comment: @Anon Depends what you refer by "every" platform. Some platforms don't have a filesystem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let me point out that the question, as stated, is a bit of a fool's errand: On platforms where there are files and such, there are well defined ways of accessing this information in the most efficient manner. Given the limited number of environments to which one must generally cater, abstracting away the functionality to simple platform specific functions is the way to go.

So, basically, reading the entire file, and counting bytes along the way is the only universal way so long as the "file" is of finite size.

One can tweak around the edges a bit (say, for a 10GB file, do we really want 10 billion [fgetc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) calls?)

For example, below I used [fread](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) to read the file in chunks up to 64K in size:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const size_t SIZE_T_MAX = (size_t) -1;
static const size_t CHUNK_SIZE = 64 * 1024;

int
calc_file_size_slowly(const char *const filename, size_t *size) {
    FILE *fp;
    int ret = -1;
    size_t bytes_read = 0;
    unsigned char *buffer = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
    assert(buffer);

    errno = 0;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) {
        goto FAIL_FOPEN;
    }

    errno = 0;
    *size = 0;
    while ((bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, CHUNK_SIZE, fp)) > 0) {
        if (ferror(fp)) {
            goto FAIL_FERROR;
        }
        if ((*size + bytes_read) > *size) {
            (*size) += bytes_read;
        }
        else {
            goto FAIL_OVERFLOW;
        }
        errno = 0;
    }

    if (feof(fp)) {
        ret = 0;
        goto DONE;
    }

FAIL_FOPEN:
    {
        ret = errno;
        goto DONE;
    }
FAIL_FERROR:
    {
        ret = errno;
        fclose(fp);
        goto DONE;
    }
FAIL_OVERFLOW:
    {
        ret = EOVERFLOW;
        fclose(fp);
        goto DONE;
    }
DONE:
    free(buffer);
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i += 1) {
        size_t size;
        if (calc_file_size_slowly(argv[i], &size) == 0) {
            printf("%s: %lu bytes\n", argv[i], size);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> dir wpi.msi
...
2015-05-15  12:12 PM         1,859,584 wpi.msi
...         
C:\...\Temp> mysizer wpi.msi     
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=65536                                       
Bytes read=24576                                       
wpi.msi: 1859584 bytes
```

Comment: Minor bits: 1) After the while loop, need another `if (ferror(fp)) {` (or something)  else code does not close file on file error which reads 0 bytes.  2) Use format `"%s: %zu bytes\n"` with `size_t`  3) `size_t` is a good type for arrays, etc, but file size may exceed `SIZE_MAX`.  Recommend using `unsigned long long` or even better `uintmax_t`.  4) although `SIZE_T_MAX` not  used, `SIZE_MAX` exist in `<stdint.h>`.  5) Using a smaller `CHUNK_SIZE`, maybe 32*1024, is more portable as `size_t` may be 16-bit and not support 64*1024.

Comment: @chux, thank you. I will revise when I have some time.